# How to deconstruct a sum of intersecting upsets

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

A set system $\mathcal{U}\subset P([n])$ is

- an *upset* if $B\supset A \in \mathcal{U}$ implies $B\in \mathcal{U}$,
- *intersecting* if $A,B\in\mathcal{U}$ implies $A\cap B \ne \emptyset$.

Note that a nonnegative linear combination of (indicator functions of) upsets is just an increasing function $f:P([n])\to[0,\infty)$, and it is a straightforward task to decompose any such $f$ back into its constituent upsets: just remove an appropriate multiple of $\mathcal{U}_1 = \lbrace A: f(A)>0 \rbrace$ and repeat.

However, given a nonnegative linear combination $f$ of *intersecting* upsets, how can one find appropriate intersecting upsets $\mathcal{U}_i$ and coefficients $\lambda_i$ such that $f = \sum \lambda_i \mathcal{U}_i$?

Comment: Not  easily.  The first idea that comes to mind is to take each U given by your first algorithm and break it into pieces, and then reassemble all the pieces until you get the desired collection.  The second idea is to consider (assuming integral combinations) nonintersecting sets A B that are in the union and considering inequality relationships.  If you get a nice collection of minimal sets in sufficient numbers,, you can generate principal intersecting upsets and see how that union compares to what you have.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.08.23

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few comments which could be a start to a reasonable solution. I won't point out (after the first time) the difference between an upset and its indicator function.

A set system $\mathcal{A}\subset P([n])$ is an *antichain* if  $B\supsetneq A \in \mathcal{A}$ implies $B\notin \mathcal{A}$

There is a natural bijection between upsets and antichains: The inclusion minimal elements of an upset $\mathcal{U}$ are an antichain $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{A_U}$ and any antichain $\mathcal{A}$ determines an upset $\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{U_A}=\lbrace B \mid B\supseteq A \text{ for some } A \in \mathcal{A} \rbrace.$  An upset is intersecting exactly if the corresponding antichain is. A *principal upset* is one of the form $\mathcal{U}_{\lbrace A \rbrace}$

The set of non-negative non-decreasing functions on $P([n])$ is a convex cone (in $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$.) We could normalize to have functions with $f(\emptyset)=0$ and $f([n])=1.$ Then we have a convex polytope $\mathbf(P)$ whose extreme points are the $0,1$ nondecreasing functions. These are just the (indicator functions of) upsets. The  intersecting upsets span some smaller polytope $\mathbf{P'}$. For functions in $\mathbf{P'}$ we have  $(*) f(A \cup B) \ge f(A)+f(B)$ when $A \cap B=\emptyset.$ This is because this property holds for intersecting upsets.

> side question:  Is the converse true -- Does the property $(*)$ characterize $\mathbf{P'}?$

We could think of a normalized non-decreasing function as giving a sort of *confidence*. Suppose an element  $x \in [n]$ is going to be chosen somehow. I could ask you what likelihood $f(A)$ you would give as your confidence that $x$ is in the particular subset $A.$ At a minimum I would expect your $f$ to be non-decreasing with $f([n])=1.$  I might further expect property $(*)$ above.

I will now drop the assumption that $f$ is normalized and settle down to the question at hand.

It should be remarked that there can be many ways to decompose a non-decreasing function into a combination of upsets. Suppose that $A_1 \cap A_2 \neq \emptyset$ and $A_1 \cup A_2=A.$  Then $$U_{\lbrace A \rbrace} + U_{\lbrace A_1,A_2 \rbrace}-U_{\lbrace A_1 \rbrace}-U_{\lbrace A_2 \rbrace}=0 \tag{**}$$

There is a unique and easily found expression of an arbitrary function $f(\cdot)$ on $P[n]$ as a linear combination of the principal upsets, provided that negative coeffients are allowed. Then there might be standard algorithms for convex sets/cones to get $f(\cdot)$ as a positive combination of intersecting upsets (or discover that there is none.) However the request is probably for a satisfyingly efficient algorithm. Here is an operation which might (or might not) lead to such an algorithm (starting with the expansion just mentioned.)

Find a set $A$ with $\lambda_{\lbrace A \rbrace} \lt 0$. Use an appropriate multiple of a productive  instance of $(**)$ to move $\lambda_A$ part way or all the way up to $0.$ The multiple should perhaps be $\min\left(\lambda_{\lbrace A_1 \rbrace},\lambda_{\lbrace A_2 \rbrace},-\lambda_{\lbrace A \rbrace} \right)$ or perhaps $-\lambda_{\lbrace A \rbrace}$ pushing the negative coefficient down. There may be useful variations involving intersecting antichains of more than two subsets.

Comment: I can at least answer that side question negatively, by taking $f$ to be the function on $P([4])$ taking the value $0$ on the sets of size $\leq 1$, $1/2$ on $2$-sets and $3$-sets, and $1$ on the $4$-set. Now check that the total mass on the $2$-level is greater than the total mass on the $3$-level, which is not true of any intersecting upset. There are in fact many more inequalities satisfied by intersecting upsets, such as $f(A_1)+\cdots+f(A_n)\geq f(B_0)+\cdots+f(B_n)$ whenever $B_k\cup B_{k+1}\subset A_{k+1}$ for all $k=0,\ldots,n−1$ and $B_0\cap B_n=\emptyset$.